# Download latest version of the file with wget

Tags: http, amazon-cloudfront, wget

Which headers I can use to download latest version of the file with wget?

I tried something like:
`wget --header="Cache-Control: no-store" --header="Pragma: no-cache"`

but after a couple of executions, I got these lines in response:

```
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Age: 7
```

The link should be unchanged (so I can't use something like `wget url.to/file.m3u8?nocache=$(bash magic)`)